# Unit testing Spring-WS SOAP endpoint fails in MockFilterChain returning 404

Tags: java, spring, soap, junit5, spring-ws

I have used Spring-WS to write a SOAP endpoint, and am now in the process of writing some tests.  However, when I try to send my request, I am getting a 404 occurring in `doFilter()` of the `MockFilterChain` class of Spring and I can't figure out why.  Is there something else I need to mock?

My endpoint is a SOAP simulator, which pulls in the WSDL-generated source files it uses from another package in my project to avoid unnecessary duplication.  So I do not have direct access to the WSDL files as a classpath resource.

My project looks like this:

**Endpoint**

```
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.PayloadRoot;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.RequestPayload;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.ResponsePayload;

@Endpoint
public class MockSoapEndpoint {

    private final ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();

    ...
    ...

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE, localPart = "soapEndpoint")
    @ResponsePayload
    public JAXBElement<MySoapResponse> chargeVolume(@RequestPayload JAXBElement<MySoapRequest> request) {
        ...
        ...
    }
```

**Config**

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class MockSoapConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(final ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet messageDispatcherServlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        messageDispatcherServlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        messageDispatcherServlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(messageDispatcherServlet, "/ws/*");
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
@WebMvcTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { MockSoapConfig.class, MockSoapEndpoint.class })
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class MockSoapEndpointTest {

    private static final String SOAP_REQUEST = ""
                    + "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"\n"
                    + "<soapenv:Header/>..."</soapenv:Envelope>\n";

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void givenNonRejectedMdnReturnChargingInformationWithCorrectMinMajCodes() throws Exception {

        final String endpoint = "http://localhost:8080/ws";

        mockMvc.perform(post(endpoint).contentType(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
                                  .content(SOAP_REQUEST)
                                  .accept(MediaType.TEXT_XML))
               .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

This test returns the `404` response code, rather than the `200` I'm expecting.  When I manually test the endpoint, using `http://localhost:8080/ws` and the same XML chunk, it works fine.

Comment: It isn't an ` @WebMvcTest`. You are testing a Soap Webservice not controllers and such.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [MockWebServiceClient](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/current/api/org/springframework/ws/test/server/MockWebServiceClient.html) instead of `MockMvc`.
As it was mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/56358651/14787187), `MockMvc` scans only `@RestController/@Controller` and omits `@Endpoint`, so your mapping `/ws/*` doesn't exist and you've got no proper `MessageDispatcher`.

Your test is going to look like:

```
 import org.springframework.xml.transform.StringSource;
 import org.springframework.ws.test.server.MockWebServiceClient;
 import static org.springframework.ws.test.server.RequestCreators.*;
 import static org.springframework.ws.test.server.ResponseMatchers.*;
 
 @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
 @ContextConfiguration("applicationContext.xml")
 public class MyWebServiceIntegrationTest {

         // a standard MessageDispatcherServlet application context, containing endpoints, mappings, etc.
         @Autowired
         private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

         private MockWebServiceClient mockClient;

         @Before
         public void createClient() throws Exception {
           mockClient = MockWebServiceClient.createClient(applicationContext);
         }

         // test the CustomerCountEndpoint, which is wired up in the application context above
         // and handles <customerCount/> messages
         @Test
         public void customerCountEndpoint() throws Exception {
           Source requestPayload = new StringSource(
                 "<customerCountRequest xmlns='http://springframework.org/spring-ws'>" +
                 "<customerName>John Doe</customerName>" +
                 "</customerCountRequest>");
           Source expectedResponsePayload = new StringSource(
                 "<customerCountResponse xmlns='http://springframework.org/spring-ws'>" +
                 "<customerCount>42</customerCount>" +
                 "</customerCountResponse>");

           mockClient.sendRequest(withPayload(requestPayload)).andExpect(payload(expectedResponsePayload));
         }
 }
```

Comment: Can you add more explanation as to why?

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have 
some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the 
target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)